# Second Activity doesn't appear the second time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am working on an application with 2 activities. The secondActivity gives information to the main one and I have to access many times to SecondActivity. The problem is that the first time everything is ok but the second time the layout (of  secondActivity) doesn't appear. The touch event respond but I have a black screen(I can get the information share and I return to my mainActivity)...

Here's my second Activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
       }
       @Override

       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                    String setData="machin";
                    Intent person = new Intent();
                    Bundle backpack = new Bundle();
                    backpack.putString("answer", setData);
                    person.putExtras(backpack);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, person);
                    finish();

                    return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                    return true;
         }
}
```

Here how I call it

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

for the moment the data share is juste a String already set but it's just to test if my two activities can communicate.

**EDIT**

I have change

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                    String setData="machin";
                    Intent person = new Intent();
                    Bundle backpack = new Bundle();
                    backpack.putString("answer", setData);
                    person.putExtras(backpack);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, person);
                    finish();

                    return true;
        }
```

into

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
       String setData="machin";
       Intent person = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
       person.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       person.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       Bundle backpack = new Bundle();
       backpack.putString("answer", setData);
       person.putExtras(backpack);
       setResult(RESULT_OK, person);

       //finish();
       startActivity(person);

       return true;
    }
```

Now the Layout appears every time but I can't get the information share (I think it's because I don't call finish() but if you know an other way to do it ...)

**EDIT 2** Thanks to Priya it's working

my SecondActivity

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                    String setData="machin";
                    Intent person = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    person.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    person.putExtra("name",setData);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, person);

                    startActivity(person);

                    return true;
   }
```

my MainActivity

```
protected void onResume(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent!=null){
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        Log.d("fdjsfdjksf","fdjskhfkdjshf"+name);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by second time? Did you jump back from the secondActivity to first and then opened the second one?

Comment: yes this is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: So you cannot open first or second again?

Comment: I think he cannot relaunch the second activity again..

Comment: Could you handle the onBackPress for the second activity by finishing it @Deliss

Comment: I can open secondActivity only 1 time. The second time it's a black screen. And I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean @OluCode

Comment: Some debug logs might help: add a log in `onCreate()` to check when it's called. Also have a look at logcat for anything unusual.

Comment: Oncreate() it's call  and nothing unusual in the logcat

Comment: can you show the code of your first activity? when you are launching the second activity again?

Comment: I call it the same way when the user touch the screen. Do you want all the code? Because I already gave the code of how I call the secondActivity.

Comment: just want to clarify if you touch the screen of first activity you are launching the second activity and for the touch event of second activity you are finishing it?

Comment: yes that's it. I will change it after but for the moment I want something simple to check if everything work ...

Comment: if oncreate is getting called there is only two possibilities either there is a problem with view or your second activity is getting finished again. Not possible to debug?

Comment: I don't think it's finish again because when I touch the black screen I switch to the mainActivity so secondActivity's touchevent() works...

Comment: Good then.. Are you doing any manipulations on your view or layout?

Comment: between the first time calling (secondActivity) and the second time calling nothing change.

Comment: finish is not required to pass your data via intent. how you are accessing the data? Do you have any logs this time?

Comment: problem may be  with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP also. It wont relaunch the activity if it is already present in stack.